# replace leading zero with a character value in Sql field

Tags: sql, sql-server, leading-zero

I'm trying to change a field's value where the leading zeros need to be replaced with an `_`. Examples:

000123 should be ___123
001234 should be __1234
0012004 should be __12004.

I thought it would have been simple but can't figure it out.

Appreciate all the help i can get!

I tried a REPLACE function but that would replace all zeroes, I only want the leading zeroes replaced

Comment: What DBMS are you using? With mysql you can use a combination of `LPAD`, `TRIM` and `LENGTH` to achieve that

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I've tried a combination of trim and replace but ultimately replaces even non zero values. I know it must be simple but can't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `try_cast` to make it an INT, then use `STR` to make it a right-aligned string of the appropriate length, then replace spaces with underscores:

```
declare @mycol varchar(11)
set @mycol = '0001234'
select replace(str(try_cast(@mycol as int),len(@mycol)),' ','_');
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for this : https://dbfiddle.uk/TExhNKgx

Answer (score 0):

With mssql I'd suggest to write an according function, which first uses `LTRIM` to remove the leading (and only the leading) zeros. And then uses `REPLICATE` to create the respective number of underscores.

```
CREATE FUNCTION replacezero
(
    @s VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @trimmed VARCHAR(MAX) = LTRIM(@s, '0')
    RETURN REPLICATE('_', LEN(@s)- LEN(@trimmed)) + @trimmed
END
GO
```

You can also do without the extra `@trimmed` but then you would need to execute `LTRIM` twice

Which you then can use as

```
SELECT dbo.replacezero(mycol) FROM my table
```

Comment: Thanks! can't get it to work in MS SQL server, but trying to 'Translate' it

Comment: Fixed two typos. But be aware the `LTRIM` function is only available as of sqlserver 2022

Comment: See also this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/rb91z4Z4

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function, [as #derpircher suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725358/3536236), is the ideal solution.

If you can't, because you only have read permission, and must use in a query you could use the following expression:

`CONCAT(REPLICATE('_', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', MyCol)-1),  TRY_CAST(MyCol AS INT));`

The `PATINDEX` function found the first occurrence of a char different from zero.

Full test code that return `__12004`:

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX) = '0012004';
SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE('_', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @value)-1),  TRY_CAST(@value AS INT));
```

**Version with fixed length to 11 and works with no leading zero**

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX) = '00012004';
SELECT 
    CONCAT(REPLICATE('_', 11-LEN(@value)),  REPLICATE('_', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @value)-1),  TRY_CAST(@value AS INT));
```

Comment: worked great except that the field length is 11 (varchar) and when the ones with one leading zero show up as : "_" and the ones with no zero are blank.

Comment: sorry sohuld have included the field length an the fact that if no leading zero then display value as is

Comment: If you know it's always six numeric character, this gets **MUCH** easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
right(
    replicate('_', 100) +
        stuff(MyCol, 1, patindex('%[^0]%', MyCol) - 1, ''),
    len(MyCol)
)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/-xUtQ_he

This is pure character manipulation. Find the index of the first non-zero character and remove everything before that via `stuff()`. Then you can use the standard left-padding technique of prepending underscores and keeping the same number of characters as the original string. This should work across all versions of SQL Server. This is a single inline expression, no casting is involved and no function installations are required.

To handle a string of all zeroes you can augment that with something like this:

```
right(
    replicate('_', 100) +
        rtrim(stuff(MyCol, 1, patindex('%[^0]%', MyCol + ' ') - 1, '')), 
    len(MyCol)
)
```